# Why this code will signal SIGSEGV?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I searched everywhere, not really sure why size 7 array will work for 6 indices but 6 will not.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main() {

    double rainRate[6];
    double averageRainfall = 0.0;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
        cout << "Enter rainfall rate for day: " << i << endl;
        cin >> rainRate[i];

        if ((rainRate[i]) >= 6.0) {
            cout << "Rainfall rate is High" << endl;
        } else if (rainRate[i] < 6.0 && rainRate[i] > 3.0) {
            cout << "Rainfall rate is Medium" << endl;
        } else if (rainRate[i] <= 3.0) {
            cout << "Rainfall rate is Low" << endl;
        }

        averageRainfall += rainRate[i];
    }

    cout << "The average rainfall rate for this week is:  " << endl;
    cout << (averageRainfall / (double) 7);

    return 0;
}
```

When changing the size of the array to 7 and assigning values to 6 indices this would run without issues but if using the exact size of the array this will cause a segmentation fault error.

Comment: Change `i <= 6` to `i < 6` in the `for`-loop. As it stands now the loop is over 7 elements.

Comment: Your termination condition is wrong. It should be `i < 6` not `i <= 6`. As it stands you are looping from 0 to 6 which is 7 iterations.

Comment: but that would be 1 index short, should the last index be unused in this case?

Comment: If the termination condition is `0 < 6` the loop will run for `0 1 2 3 4 5`, which is 6 elements. Remember index `0` when counting the number of elements ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the size of `double rainRate[6];` is 6, but your code tries to access 7 items: `[0]`,`[1]`,`[2]`,`[3]`,`[4]`,`[5]`,`[6]`.

If you have an array of `n` elements, valid indexes are `0`-`n-1`. `0`-`5` in your case.

**Solution**: replace `i <= 6` with `i < 6`.

Comment: I see, so any defined array of any size would always be `n-1` so in this case rainRate[6] cannot be used?

Comment: @YrandomIrandom Nah, it's size *is* 6. First element is #0 and last one is #5. | Now your loop works 7 times, but your array has 6 elements. You can modify loop condition, so it will work 6 times. Or you can expand the array to 7 elements.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation *thumbs up*

Answer (score 2):

You are **not** using the exact size of the array. `rainRate` has 6 elements which are indexed as 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5.

Fix by using `i < 6` rather than `i <= 6`, or increase the size of your array by 1.

Finally, consider using `size_t` as the array index type. Using `unsigned` *could* get you into trouble in future as it's maximum size could be as small as 65535 and an array can contain many more than this number of elements these days. Some folk advocate using `ptrdiff_t` (as that will support negative indexing) but I'm of ilk of using `size_t`.